# UPDATE based on SELECT result

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I'm trying to UPDATE a table based on a sub-query on itself. So I need sub-query's result as parameters in UPDATE statement.

I tried below with no success:

```
UPDATE xx
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT r.id as id, w.state as state
    ...
) yy
SET xx.state = yy.state WHERE xx.id = yy.id;
```

**EDIT:**
Full query:

```
UPDATE dpcio_request xx
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT r.id as id, w.state as state
    FROM dpcio_request r
    JOIN dpcio_request_wf w
    ON (w.dpcio_request_id = r.id)
    WHERE w.id IN ( SELECT MAX(id)
            FROM `dpcio_request_wf`
            GROUP BY dpcio_request_id )
    ) r2 ON r1.id = r2.id
) yy ON yy.id = xx.id
SET xx.state = yy.state;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you have no special calculation on the subquery  and assuming that it is from a different table, you can directly join the tables,

```
UPDATE table1 a
       INNER JOIN table2 b
          ON a.id = b.id
SET    a.colName = b.value
```

**UPDATE 1**

here's a simplified version of the query,

```
UPDATE  dpcio_request a
        INNER JOIN dpcio_request_wf b
            ON a.id = b.dpcio_request_wf
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  dpcio_request_id, MAX(id) max_ID
            FROM    dpcio_request_wf
            GROUP   BY dpcio_request_id
        ) c ON  b.id = c.max_ID AND
                b.dpcio_request_id = c.dpcio_request_id
SET     a.state = b.state
```

Comment: how about joining table `dpcio_request` directly with `dpcio_request_wf` and calculating on the max id on the subquery?